# C# Entity Framework Core - LINQ check the presence of one array in another

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

If you try to find entities that contain genres from the query (they may also contain other genres that are not in the query), you will get an error. I tried many options but ended up with 3 requests.

Request.genres is a list string.

```
query = query.Where(g => request.genres.All(r => g.Genres.Any(gameGenre => gameGenre.Equals(new StringForGame(r)))));
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'r => ShapedQueryExpression:
> QueryExpression:
> Projection Mapping:
> EmptyProjectionMember -> EntityProjectionExpression: StringForGame
> SELECT 1
> FROM Games_Genres AS g
> ShaperExpression: EntityShaperExpression:
> GameProfile.Domain.Entities.GameEntites.Game.Genres#StringForGame
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
>
> .Where(namelessParameter{0} => object.Equals(
> objA: (object)EF.Property(EntityShaperExpression:
> GameProfile.Domain.Entities.GameEntites.Game
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> , "Id"),
> objB: (object)EF.Property(namelessParameter{0}, "GameId")))
> .AsQueryable()
> .Any(o => o.GameString.Equals(new StringForGame(r)))' could not be translated.

```
query = query.Where(g => g.Genres.Any(gg => request.genres.All(r=> gg.GameString == r)));
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'r => EntityShaperExpression:
> GameProfile.Domain.Entities.GameEntites.Game.Genres#StringForGame
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> .GameString == r' could not be translated.

This query works but doesn't give me the result I need.

```
query = query.Where(g => g.Genres.Any(gg => request.genres.Contains(gg.GameString)));
// and this too
query = query.Where(g => g.Genres.All(gg => request.genres.Contains(gg.GameString)));
```

For context

```
public async Task<List<Game>> Handle(GetGamesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        var query = _context.Games.AsQueryable();

        if (request.sort == "titleAtoZ")
        {
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Title);
        }
        else if (request.sort == "titleZtoA")
        {
            query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title);
        }
        else if (request.sort == "dateAscending")
        {
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.ReleaseDate);
        }
        else if (request.sort == "dateDescending")
        {
            query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.ReleaseDate);
        }

        if (request.releaseDateOf != DateTime.MinValue && request.releaseDateTo != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.ReleaseDate >= request.releaseDateOf && x.ReleaseDate <= request.releaseDateTo);
        }
        else if (request.releaseDateOf == DateTime.MinValue && request.releaseDateTo != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.ReleaseDate <= request.releaseDateTo);
        }
        else if (request.releaseDateOf != DateTime.MinValue && request.releaseDateTo == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.ReleaseDate >= request.releaseDateOf);
        }

        if (request.nsfw == "yes")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Nsfw == true);
        }
        else if (request.nsfw == "no")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Nsfw == false);
        }

        if (request.genres is not null && request.genres.Count > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(g => g.Genres.Any(gg => request.genres.Contains(gg.GameString)));
            //query = query.Where(g => g.Genres.Any(gg => request.genres.All(r=> gg.GameString == r)));
            //query = query.Where(g => request.genres.All(r => g.Genres.Any(gameGenre => gameGenre.Equals(new StringForGame(r)))));
        }

        int skipGame = request.page * 50;
        query = query.Skip(skipGame).Take(50);
        var games = await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        return games;
}

public sealed class Game : Entity
{
    public Game(Guid id,
                string title,
                DateTime releaseDate,
                Uri headerImage,
                bool nsfw,
                string description,
                ICollection<StringForGame> developers,
                ICollection<StringForGame> publishers,
                ICollection<StringForGame> genres,
                ICollection<UriForGame> screenshots,
                ICollection<UriForGame> shopsLinkBuyGame,
                int achievementsCount) : this(id,title,releaseDate,headerImage,nsfw,description,achievementsCount)
    {
        Developers = developers;
        Publishers = publishers;
        Genres = genres;
        Screenshots = screenshots;
        ShopsLinkBuyGame = shopsLinkBuyGame;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// EF constructor
    /// </summary>
    private Game(Guid id,
                string title,
                DateTime releaseDate,
                Uri headerImage,
                bool nsfw,
                string description,
                int achievementsCount) : base(id)
    {
        Title = title;
        ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
        HeaderImage = headerImage;
        Nsfw = nsfw;
        Description = description;
        AchievementsCount = achievementsCount;
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; private set; }
    public Uri HeaderImage { get; private set; }
    public bool Nsfw { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<UriForGame> Screenshots { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<StringForGame> Genres { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class StringForGame : ValueObject
{
    public StringForGame(string gameString)
    {
        GameString = gameString;
    }

    public string GameString { get; private init; }
    
    public override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
    {
        yield return GameString;
    }
}

public abstract class ValueObject : IEquatable<ValueObject>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues();

    public bool Equals(ValueObject? other)
    {
        return other is not null && ValuesAreEqual(other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is ValueObject valueObject && ValuesAreEqual(valueObject);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetAtomicValues().Aggregate(default(int), HashCode.Combine);
    }

    private bool ValuesAreEqual(ValueObject other)
    {
        return GetAtomicValues().SequenceEqual(other.GetAtomicValues());
    }
}
```

I don't really understand what the problem is and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Version used: EF Core 7.0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relatively well known is that the only supported method on *in memory* collections inside LINQ to Entities query in all EF ("classic" and Core) versions is `Contains`.

Which works fine with `Any` type criteria like

```cs
query.Any(x => collection.Contains(Field(x)))
```

but not for `All` type criteria like

```cs
query.All(x => collection.Contains(Field(x)))
```

most probably because of the lack of the corresponding SQL construct (even though they do that for some other LINQ expressions).

And the usual (and the only known) workaround is to use the "counting matches" equivalent of LINQ `All`

```cs
query.Count(x => collection.Contains(Field(x))) == collection.Count()
```

(in some version you might need to store `collection.Count()` in a variable outside the query and use that variable inside).

With that being said, the solution in your case is something like

```cs
query = query.Where(g => 
    g.Genres.Count(gg => request.genres.Contains(gg.GameString)) == request.Genres.Count()
);
```